# При попытке настройки конвертации .scss в .css с помощью команды --watch появляется ошибка, без этой команды компилирует правильно

Tags: sass

windows vista, установил Ruby, создал необходимые папку и директории scss и css, index.html.

В командной строке прописал:

```
 >MySass>sass scss/style.scss css/style.css
```

нажал <kbd>enter</kbd>, всё хорошо скомпилировалось.

А вот когда ввожу:

```
>MySass>sass --watch scss/style.scss:css/style.css
```

то выдает ошибку.

Comment: Думаю что компилятор не понимает смешение директорий и файлов с watch

Comment: извините, что отнял время. вопрос решился : в пути к папке с файлом была папка с кириллицей. исправил, всё заработало. как я такое не заметил? стыдно!